# Trouble getting AMQP endpoint going in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, amqp, apache-karaf, blueprint

I am trying to use AMQP queues as both the start and end of a route. I am having trouble getting this to work, following the example at http://camel.apache.org/amqp.html

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I am deploying this in a blueprint container in karaf.

My setup is:

```xml
  <bean id="amqpConnectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl"
        factory-method="createFromURL">
    <argument value="${IssBroker.url}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="amqpConnection"
        class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqpConnectionFactory"/>
  </bean>

    ...

    <route>
      <from uri="amqp:{{IssFrom.queue}}"/>
      <process ref="issPreprocessor"/>
      <unmarshal ref="IssRequest"/>
      <process ref="webServiceProcessor"/>
      <to uri="webService"/>
      <process ref="packageWebServiceReplyForIss"/>
      <to uri="amqp:{{IssTo.queue}}"/>
    </route>
```

When I start this in karaf I get:

`2015-10-08 13:34:00,968 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | BlueprintCamelContext            | 109 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.15.3 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(myCamelContext) due connectionFactory must be specified`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:293)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1131)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1140)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:504)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.configureMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:967)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:71)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your amqpConnectionFactory bean is ending up null, one of the reasons for that would be that your IssBroker.url property is null or malformed. Have you got this property overridden in your karaf container?

### More likely answer:

You've given your JmsComponent the id amqpConnection and then used `amqp:${{IssFrom.queue}}` change the id to amqp or change the component used in the route to `amqpConnection:${{IssFrom.queue}}`

Comment: Yes, it is in the .cfg file in <karaf-home>/etc

`IssBroker.url=amqp://localhost:5672`

Comment: Your new theory was the ticket. After that I had to add one more jar to the karaf deploy dir (qpid-amqp-1-0-common.jar). Thanks! I will go back to the Camel AMQP folks and submit a correction to their instructions.